# UINavigationItem.LargeTitleDisplayMode.never still shows background for large title when wrapped in UISplitViewController

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

The new iOS 15 navigation bars are translucent when scrolled to the top by default. Because I am showing a UIMapView, I don't want this behaviour for this particular ViewController, while keeping this new behaviour for the rest of the app.

I have `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` set to `.never`.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        self.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

But this results in the navigation bar showing the it's background as if the large title is still showing. Setting the `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.always` and back to `.never` doesn't fix it.

[image]

I am only able to reproduce this behaviour when the `UINavigationController` is wrapped in a `UISplitViewController` like this:

[image]

When reproducing this without the `UISplitViewController`, with just the `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController` with button -> `UIViewController` with `UIMapView`, the `UINavigationBar` functions just fine.

Strangely, when running this example on iOS 14, the `UINavigationBar`'s appearance is just fine, but I am unable to interact with the map in the area that is covered when running on iOS 15. (See https://youtu.be/XqbzOimhqGA)

What am I doing wrong here? Or is this an iOS bug?

My testing project that I used can be found on GitHub: [Zandor300/iOS15NavigationBar](https://github.com/Zandor300/iOS15NavigationBar)